# Optimising Queries in nHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, reporting-services

I'm using the following code to create a report (the list of objects returned is used as the datasource in an rdlc file).

I'm querying a list of TNA objects, each of which can contain a list of Training objects.  Each Training object can contain a Course object.  Each TNA object contains an Employee object.

However, I'm finding that the code takes a long time to run.

In addition, if we have more than a few hundred TNA objects, we get an out of memory error before the query completes.

I don't have a lot of experience with nHibernate - is it possible to optimise this code or are there any obvious errors in the code?

Thanks in advance.

```
    DetachedCriteria dc = this.BuildPermissions(moduleUser, typeof(TNA));
    ICriteria criteria = dc.GetExecutableCriteria(this.Session);
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id));

    criteria.CreateAlias("TrainingRecords", "TrainingRecords", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Eq("TrainingRecords.TNAStatus", TNAStatus.Optional)));

    ProjectionList projectionList =
        Projections.ProjectionList()
                   .Add(Projections.Property("OrgUnit"), "OrgUnit")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("Employee"), "Employee")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.Course"), "Course")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.RequiredBy"), "RequiredBy")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("TNATemplate"), "TNATemplate")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("TrainingRecords.TNAStatus"), "TNAStatus")
                   .Add(Projections.Property("Customer"), "Customer");


    ICriteria result = criteria.SetProjection(projectionList)
                               .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TrainingMatrix>());

    return result.List<TrainingMatrix>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First , Please add .ShowSql in the nhibernate configuration and examine the sql statement produced by nhibernate. You can put it in the SQL Managment Studio etc and see the performance.

second, you can use tools like SQL profiler to examine what is happening in database.

third, please make sure you have proper keys and indexes created in DB

fourth , check how you initialize the your sessionfactory . Are you you creating new sessionfactory each time

fifth , See you can use caching of nhibernate.

sixth , examine how you call the program from report as datasource. look for any infinite loops, datasource repeatedly binding again and again etc.

seventh , if do not need all data from second table at once , instead on projections you can use lazy loading and get the objects on a need basis

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been through most of these steps, and I need all of the data at once.  The problem appears to be the number of objects which are returned - many thousands - which appear to be causing the out of memory error.